# Aggregation Annotation Not Working With Unwind and Match

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I am attempting to run a custom aggregation query with Spring Boot and MongoDB that returns the sum of fields in a sub-document that match a certain criteria.

Currently, I have a query that returns the sum of fields in a sub-document, but does not take into consideration the matching of criteria.

Working query:

```java
@Aggregation(pipeline = {"{'$project': {'_id': '$_id', 'date': '$date', \n" +
            "      'confirmed': {'$sum': '$states.confirmed'}, \n" +
            "      'deaths': {'$sum': '$states.deaths'}, \n" +
            "      'recovered': {'$sum': '$states.recovered'}, \n" +
            "      'active': {'$sum': '$states.active'}}}}"
})
AggregationResults<LineChart> aggregateAllStates(Sort sort);
```

Returns:

```json
[
    {
        "date": "2020-04-12",
        "confirmed": 555613,
        "deaths": 22107,
        "active": 500306,
        "recovered": 67139
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-04-13",
        "confirmed": 580876,
        "deaths": 23633,
        "active": 615609,
        "recovered": 78924
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-04-14",
        "confirmed": 607926,
        "deaths": 25931,
        "active": 534076,
        "recovered": 85408
    },
etc...
]
```

The next aggregation does not work:

```java
@Aggregation(pipeline = {"{'$unwind':{path:'$states'}},\n" +
            "  {'$match': {'states.state': 'alabama'}},\n" +
            "  {'$project':{_id:'$_id', date: '$date',\n" +
            "    confirmed: {'$sum': '$states.confirmed'},\n" +
            "    active: {'$sum': '$states.active'},\n" +
            "    deaths: {'$sum': '$states.deaths'},\n" +
            "    recovered: {'$sum': '$states.recovered'}\n" +
            "  }}"
})
AggregationResults<LineChart> aggregateOneState(String name, Sort sort);
```

Returns:

```json
[
    {
        "date": "2020-04-12",
        "confirmed": null,
        "deaths": null,
        "active": null,
        "recovered": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-04-12",
        "confirmed": null,
        "deaths": null,
        "active": null,
        "recovered": null
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-04-12",
        "confirmed": null,
        "deaths": null,
        "active": null,
        "recovered": null
    },
etc..
]
```

Running this query in the mongo shell works perfectly fine. In Spring it returns a lot more data (pretty sure it is returning the unwound data) with all fields nulled out.

```sh
db.us_collection.aggregate([
  {'$unwind':{path:'$states'}},
  {'$match': {'states.state': 'alabama'}},
  {'$project':{_id:'$_id', date: '$date',
    confirmed: {'$sum': '$states.confirmed'},
    active: {'$sum': '$states.active'},
    deaths: {'$sum': '$states.deaths'},
    recovered: {'$sum': '$states.recovered'}
  }},
  {'$sort':{date:-1}}
  ])
```

Edit:

How the data looks in MongoDB

```json
[
    {
        "id": "6017455f7517801dda88bc56",
        "date": "2020-04-12",
        "states": [
            {
                "state": "alabama",
                "confirmed": 3667,
                "deaths": 93,
                "recovered": 0,
                "active": 3470,
                "incident_rate": 75.98802021,
                "mortality_rate": 2.610159978
            },
            {
                "state": "alaska",
                "confirmed": 272,
                "deaths": 8,
                "recovered": 66,
                "active": 264,
                "incident_rate": 45.50404936,
                "mortality_rate": 2.941176471
            },
            {
                "state": "arizona",
                "confirmed": 3542,
                "deaths": 115,
                "recovered": 0,
                "active": 3427,
                "incident_rate": 48.66242224,
                "mortality_rate": 3.246753247
            },
            // continues list of states in same format
        ]
    },
    // more documents in same layout for different days
]
```

Comment: You can include an input document sample for the aggregation that is not working.

Comment: @prasad_ Just edited with how the data looks in the MongoDB.

Comment: Instead of `$unwind` you can use `$filter` (or even `$reduce`) -  this way you can avoid more stages and the task will be complete in just one `$addFields` (or `$project`) stage.

Comment: This would be a good optimization. The problem of the original query not working in Spring, but working in Mongo shell still exists though. Is `$unwind` not supported with the `@Aggregation` annotation or is my query just wrong?

Comment: _"... $unwind not supported with the @Aggregation annotation..."_. The API docs doesn't say anything about such restrictions. What version of MongoDB and Spring Data are you working with?

Comment: Here is my build.gradle file: https://github.com/bhaden94/Covid19-tracker-V2-API/blob/master/build.gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up being a comma in the wrong place.

If there is a multi-step query inside of an `@Aggregation` annotation then they must be split up by commas **outside of the string**.

Example of bad query that won't work:

```js
@Aggregation(pipeline = {"{'$unwind':{path:'$states'}},\n" +
            "  {'$match': {'states.state': 'alabama'}},\n" +
            "  {'$project':{_id:'$_id', date: '$date',\n" +
            "    confirmed: {'$sum': '$states.confirmed'},\n" +
            "    active: {'$sum': '$states.active'},\n" +
            "    deaths: {'$sum': '$states.deaths'},\n" +
            "    recovered: {'$sum': '$states.recovered'}\n" +
            "  }}"
})
```

Notice the comma that separates the `$unwind`, `$match`, and `$prject` are all within the string.

Example of working aggregation query:

```js
@Aggregation(pipeline = {"{'$unwind':{path:'$states'}}",
            "  {'$match': {'states.state': 'alabama'}}",
            "  {'$project':{_id:'$_id', date: '$date',\n" +
            "    confirmed: {'$sum': '$states.confirmed'},\n" +
            "    active: {'$sum': '$states.active'},\n" +
            "    deaths: {'$sum': '$states.deaths'},\n" +
            "    recovered: {'$sum': '$states.recovered'}\n" +
            "  }}"
})
```

Notice now that the separating commas are outside of the string.

I also took the advice from @prasad_ and removed the `$unwind` and instead used filter to speed up the aggregation.

Here is my final working aggregation query:

```js
@Aggregation(pipeline = {"" +
            "{'$project': {'_id': '$_id', 'date': '$date', \n" +
            "      'states': {'$filter': {\n" +
            "          'input': '$states', \n" +
            "          'as': 'item', \n" +
            "          'cond': {'$eq': ['$$item.state', '?0']}}}}" +
            "}",
            "{'$project': {'_id': '$_id', 'date': '$date', \n" +
            "      'confirmed': {'$sum': '$states.confirmed'}, \n" +
            "      'deaths': {'$sum': '$states.deaths'}, \n" +
            "      'recovered': {'$sum': '$states.recovered'}, \n" +
            "      'active': {'$sum': '$states.active'}}}" +
            "}"
})
AggregationResults<LineChart> aggregateOneState(String name, Sort sort);
```